# PHP Zend Framework - How do I use union all? 

Tags: php, zend-framework

How do I use `UNION ALL` in this fashion in Zend Framework?

```
(select id from astrology where commu_time_from  <= '11:51' and commu_time_to >= '11:51' and user_id=1 and appo_date='03/01/2017') union all
(select id from facereading where commu_time_from  <= '11:51' and commu_time_to >= '11:51' and user_id=1 and appo_date='03/01/2017') union all
(select id from numerology where commu_time_from  <= '11:51' and commu_time_to >= '11:51' and user_id=1 and appo_date='03/01/2017') union all
(select id from palmistry where commu_time_from  <= '11:51' and commu_time_to >= '11:51' and user_id=1 and appo_date='03/01/2017') union all
(select id from solutions where commu_time_from  <= '11:51' and commu_time_to >= '11:51' and user_id=1 and appo_date='03/01/2017') union all
(select id from vastu where commu_time_from  <= '11:51' and commu_time_to >= '11:51' and user_id=1 and appo_date='03/01/2017')
```

I also need to figure out how to track the total # of rows in the results.

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass an array of `Zend_Db_Select` into the union() method. The second parameter to be passed to the `union()` method to perform the type of UNION. In your case, use  `Zend_Db_Select::SQL_UNION_ALL` as a constant.

For e.g.

```
$sql1 = $db->select();
$sql2 = "SELECT ...";

$select = $db->select()
    ->union(array($sql1, $sql2), Zend_Db_Select::SQL_UNION_ALL );
```

Reference:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.union

Answer (score 4):

From [API Docs](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/_Db_Select.html#Zend_Db_Select%3a%3aunion%28%29):

> **`union( array $select = array,  $type = self ) : Zend_Db_Select`**
>
> Adds a UNION clause to the query.
>
> The first parameter has to be an array of Zend_Db_Select or sql query strings.
>
> ```
> $sql1 = $db->select();  
> $sql2 = "SELECT ...";  
> $select = $db->select()  
>              ->union(array($sql1, $sql2))
>              ->order("id");
> ```

The same example and some additional text can be found in the [Example #28 Example of union() method](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.union) in the ZF Reference guide. Apart from that, you can always use `Zend_Db_Expr` when you dont need the Query Builder.

Answer (score 2):

```
$select = union($select1, $select2, self::SQL_UNION_ALL).
```

Ex:

```
$select1 = 'select A from table1';
$select2 = 'select A from table2';

$select = $db->select()->union($select1, $select2, Zend_Db_Select::SQL_UNION_ALL);

echo $select;
```

Result: (SELECT A FROM TABLE1) UNION ALL (SELECT A FROM TABLE2).

Answer (score 0):

**here is the running example**

**in raw Sql**

```
select CONCAT_WS(' ', u.fname, u.lname) as user_name, u.image, c.* from challenge c inner join challenge_user cu on (cu.challenge_id = c.id) inner join users u on (u.id = c.user_id) where c.user_id = '1' group by c.id

union all 
select CONCAT_WS(' ', u.fname, u.lname) as user_name, u.image, c.* from challenge c inner join challenge_user cu on (cu.challenge_id = c.id) inner join users u on (u.id = c.user_id) where concat('%,',c.challenger_user_id,',%') LIKE concat( '%,"1",%' ) group by c.id
```

**in zend**

```
 $sql1 = $this->select()->setIntegrityCheck(FALSE)
      ->from(array('c'=>'challenge'),array('user_name'=>new Zend_Db_Expr("CONCAT_WS(' ',                      u.fname, u.lname)"),'u.image'))
        ->joinInner(array('cu'=>'challenge_user'), 'cu.challenge_id = c.id')
         ->joinInner(array('u'=>'users'),'u.id = c.user_id')
         ->where('c.user_id = ?','1')
          ->group('c.id');
 $sql2 = $this->select()->setIntegrityCheck(FALSE)->from(array('c'=>'challenge'),array('user_name'=>new Zend_Db_Expr("CONCAT_WS(' ', u.fname, u.lname)"),'u.image'))
               ->joinInner(array('cu'=>'challenge_user'), 'cu.challenge_id = c.id')
               ->joinInner(array('u'=>'users'),'u.id = c.user_id')
               ->where(new Zend_Db_Expr("concat('%,',c.challenger_user_id,',%') LIKE concat( '%,"1",%' )"))->group('c.id');

$select = $this->select()->union(array($sql1,$sql2),  Zend_Db_Select::SQL_UNION_ALL);

$data =  $this->fetchAll($select);
```

**Hope it will help some one**